# Slack: I've created a channel, don't want all of the clutter

Tags: slack

I've created a channel in Slack; the goal is for it just be a repository of links, without a lot of discussion.

Is there a way to have a channel not auto generate all of the minute alerts, about every little thing that happens? (see pic).
[image: Slack channel clutter]

I want to keep this channel as decluttered as I can.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to hide all the messages there. You can turn join and leave message off though.

[Slack documentation on how to turn off join and leave messages](https://slack.com/intl/en-in/help/articles/115002695043-Manage-join-and-leave-messages)

> 1. From your desktop, click your workspace name in the top left.
> 2. Select `Settings & administration`, then click `Workspace settings`.
> 3. Scroll down to the Join & leave messages section and click `Expand`.
> 4. Tick or untick the box next to `Show a message when people join or leave channels`.
> 5. Click `Save`.